# How to get Calendar.MONTH from a given WEEK_OF_YEAR, DAY_OF_WEEK,YEAR

Tags: java, calendar

Knowing the year, week of year and day of week is it possible to obtain the month of year and the day of month. For example

```
 // corresponding to September 15, 2012 if week starts on Monday
 int weekNum = 38;
 int dayNum = 6;
 int year = 2012;

 // set the calendar instance the a week of year and day in the future
  Calendar aGMTCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
 aGMTCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);    
 aGMTCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,weekNum ); 
 aGMTCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,dayNum );
 aGMTCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);

// get the month and day of month
 int   monthGMT = aGMTCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH + 1); // returns 38  not 9

 int   dayOfMonthNumGMT = aGMTCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
 // returns 14 but I wanted 15
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This should be

```
// +1 to the value of month returned, not to the value of MONTH constant.
int monthGMT = aGMTCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you obtain the `monthGMT` has a type. It should be:

```
int monthGMT = aGMTCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

Put the line below after each `aGMTCalendar.set()` call and you will see that after calling the `dayNum` one, the date changes from 15 to 14. The `aGMTCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayNum)` ignores the `setFirstDayOfWeek`, which is however considered when setting the `WEEK_OF_YEAR`.

```
System.out.println(aGMTCalendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Although I attempted to set the first day of the week to Monday (Monday should be 1) via       aGMTCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY)  when I input   dayOfWeekNum weekNum  = 6 38 I get month/day  = 9/14

Comment: Thanks again for your help... I'm still struggling

Answer (score 0):

Try `Calendar.SATURDAY` constant instead of `6` literal.

`Calendar.SATURDAY` is in fact `7` not `6`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // corresponding to September 15, 2012 if week starts on Monday
 int weekNum = 38;
 int dayNum = 6;
 int year = 2012;

  // set the calendar instance the a week of year and day in the future
  Calendar aGMTCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
 aGMTCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);    
 aGMTCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,weekNum ); 
 aGMTCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,dayNum );
 aGMTCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);

 // get the month and day of month
 int   monthGMT = aGMTCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; 
 // should be 10
 int   dayOfMonthNumGMT = aGMTCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1; 
 // should be 15
```